# iOS: How can I prevent a UITextField from going off screen

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, uitextfield

I am currently developing an application which has two UILabels inside a Vertical StackView, two UITextFields inside a Vertical StackView, and both of those Vertical StackViews inside one Horizontal StackView as such:

[image]

I have constraints put in place. When the application runs on bigger devices such as an iPhone 11, it looks perfect as you can see here:

[image]

But if I switch to a smaller device like the iPhone 8 you can see the lines hug the edge of the phone as such:

[image]

The way I  make the underline for the TextField is by using a class I created called StyledTextField. It looks like this:

```
class StyledTextField: UITextField {

var bottomLine = CALayer()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    styleTextField()
}

private func styleTextField() {
    font = UIFont(name: "Quicksand", size: UIFont.labelFontSize)
    
    // Create the bottom line
    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - 2, width: frame.width, height: 2)
    
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = Environment.Colours.primary.cgColor
    
    // Remove border on text field
    borderStyle = .none
    
    // Add the line to the text field
    layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
}

func makeUnderlineLight() {
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = Environment.Colours.primaryAssisted.cgColor
}
}
```

In the Storyboard, I assign the UITextField class to be that of the "StyledTextField".

Additionally, in my `viewDidLoad` function on the Controller that deals with the UITextFields, I call the `setUpUI()` function which does the following:

```
func setUpUI() {
    title = "Add Task"
    
    taskNameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Name", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Environment.Colours.lightGray])
    moreInfoTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "(Optional)", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Environment.Colours.lightGray])
    
    setUpDatePicker()
    moreInfoTextField.makeUnderlineLight()
    
    if isEditing() {
        showTaskToEdit()
    }
    view.backgroundColor = Environment.Colours.secondary
}
```

As you can see, I call the `makeUnderlineLight()` StyledTextField function once inside there.

Thank you!

Comment: “I'm certain the issue has nothing to do with how I create the underline.” Any time you’re certain, you’re probably wrong. And so in this case. I’m betting it is exactly just the underline that’s the problem.

Comment: The way to know whether the text field is really going offscreen is to use the View Debugger. Try that.

Comment: @matt Okay, fair enough. I added the code for creating the underline if you are interested.

Comment: No, you didn't. Everything depends on _when_ you call that method, and that is exactly what you continue to conceal. — You see, what I'm suspecting is that you call it too early. It depends on the `frame` of the text field. But if you call it before autolayout operates, you will get the _wrong frame_, which is exactly what you are complaining about. You need to _coordinate_ this method with the resizing of the text field, no matter how and when that happens.

Comment: Also your method is faulty because if it is called more than once you will get more than one underline layer. But it _needs_ to be called more than once because the text field can be resized.

Comment: Also, did you do what I suggested — use the View Debugger? It will tell you instantly whether it is the text field or just the underline that is running offscreen. All you have to do is look.

Comment: @matt Sorry if I haven't been providing proper information. I did the View Debugger and it seems like you are correct. The issue does have to do with how I do the underline. Additionally, if I select the "iPhone SE" in the "View As" section of Storyboard and then load the iPhone 8 simulator, the underlining works. Which means I think you're also right about it being called before Autolayout operates. For that reason, I'm going to update my question and show exactly how I do the underline.

Comment: Yup, I go back to what I said in my first comment. When you say "I'm certain" what you are really saying is "I refuse to check this assumption". That's no way to program. :)

Comment: @matt You're correct. That was a foolish mistake. I have updated my question. Hopefully I put the right information this time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple two-step solution:

- Rewrite `styleTextField` so that it keeps a reference to the underline layer and *removes* the underline layer if it already exists, before making a new one.
- Move the call to `styleTextField()` to `layoutSubviews`. (Don't forget to call `super`.)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, but quick question. Could I remove the "styleTextField()" call in the required init function in the StyledTextField class. Then in the didLayoutSubviews function call the "styleTextField" on the TextFields?

Comment: You can put the call wherever you like as long as it is associated with layout.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work unfortunately. I'll mess around with it though and see if I can get it. I think you put me on the right path so thank you.

Comment: Well I suggest that you do exactly what my answer said, and not mess with it.

Comment: I got it working. I'm just adding this here in case someone comes across this. The frame of UITextFields do not update in the viewDidLayoutSubviews. So for people wondering, the way I fixed this issue is by using Matt's suggestion of viewDidLayoutSubview and calling the styleTextField method in there, but before doing that I called the function "setNeedsLayout()" then "layoutIfNeeded()" on the TextField first.

Comment: @Julian Cool! Feel free to add that _as an answer_. That's totally fine, and answers live on, whereas comments can get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

select Your "More Info:" label and set horizontal compress resistanse priority to 1000

it ca be found here: [image]

Comment: Thank you a bunch Kstin! That helped with the styling of the application. Although the underline issue is still there.